# How to add duplicates from one excel column into the rest of the sheet?

Tags: excel

I am working on a Excel sheet that I will use later in ArcMap.
I have two sheets with information that I want to combine into one. Lets call them "old sheet" and "new sheet". 
Both sheets have a column with id-numbers that are the same numbers, but on the new sheet there are duplicates because there are several rows of new information on each id-number.

I want to add the sheets together and I want the information on the old sheet to follow the duplicates on the new sheet, so the old infomation also is duplicated.
How can I do that?

EDIT: I`ve tried using 
=VLOOKUP(B2,oldsheet!$B$2:'newsheet'!$A$2)
("Old"- and "New" sheet refrences the picture under with old and new information).

Formula fails, and I don`t know how to fix it.

[image: Picture that graphically explains how the sheets look and how I want them to look]

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: I`ve tried using VLOOKUP function, but I`m not sure if it didn`t work because I did it wrong or because it can`t be done that way. I`ve tried finding an answer for a few hours, but I am at a loss now. The more I read and research the less certain I am of how to do it.

Comment: Edit your question to show the `VLOOKUP` you tried. It almost certainly can be done using `VLOOKUP` - or `INDEX` & `MATCH`, or using Power Query... it will be easier to help when we can see what you've already tried.

Comment: Sorry! I put both the old and the new sheet into one to help me find a solution and I forgot when i put it up to you guys. I`ll add a new one.

Comment: Edited to show the VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

Using `VLOOKUP`

In cell C2 of NewSheet, and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,OldSheet!$A$1:$B$4,1,FALSE)
```

In cell D2 of NewSheet, and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,OldSheet!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```